# JSON: which pathway to access the key value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

**Given a json such :**

```
 var WNES_list = {
     "India":{ "W": 67.0, "N":37.5, "E": 99.0, "S": 5.0, "vert_%": 106 },
     };
```

I know how to access values :

```
var myValue = WNES_list.India.W;
```

**How to access to a key such `W`, or `India` ?**

Comment: What do you mean "access to a key"? Do you want to iterate over the key names? In this case, use a [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop.

Comment: Not to be nitpicky but that isn't JSON, it's object literal notation.

Comment: I want to get the key, literally "India".

Comment: @Sushanth's answer does just that, have you tried it yet?

Comment: Sush's answer iterate through the values. I'am looking for a pathway, similar to what is used for values, in ex: `WNES_list.India.W`

Comment: You could always go and steal the parts used for underscore's `.where()` which should be what you are looking for if I understand you correctly: http://underscorejs.org/#where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for loop to access the `key`

```
for (var key in WNES_list) {
    var obj = WNES_list[key];
    console.log(key); // logs : India, France
    for (var k in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            console.log(k);
        }
    }
}
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5XfXt/)**

Comment: Shouldn't there be a obj.hasOwnProperty(key) in there somewhere?

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton.. It is a good idea to add that check if you believe extra properties are added to the object prototype. Thanks for pointing out though..